# React Fullcalendar v5 - events source not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

For performance purposes, especially with interactions, I'm trying to convert my fullcalendar component with event sources, rather than grouping all my API calls in a Promise.all and sending an array of events.

The problem is that my sources are promises, and they do send an array in the right format, but the FullCalendar schedule is still empty, and I don't understand why...

Here's my component (simplified):

```
<FullCalendar
    ref={calendarRef}
    schedulerLicenseKey={process.env.SCHEDULER_KEY}
    plugins={[resourceTimelinePlugin, interactionPlugin]}
    initialView='resourceTimelineMonth'
    locale="fr"
    timeZone="Europe/Paris"
    height="100%"
    headerToolbar={false}
    resources={filteredResources}
    eventSources={[
       {
          //Some parameters depends on react hook states
          events: satisfactionSourceEvents(planningType, filteredResources, horizon, draft, execId, parseInt(selectedSolution))
       }
    ]}
   nowIndicator
   slotDuration= "24:00:00"
   eventClick={handleEventClick}
   slotLabelContent={HeaderContent}
   resourceLabelContent={renderResourceContent}
   eventContent={renderEventContent}
   dateClick={handleDateClick}
```

The `satisfactionSourceEvents` function is in another file :

```
function satisfactionSourceEvents(planningType: PlanningType, resources: GroupResource[], horizon: any, draft?: PlanningDraft, execId?: number, solId?: number): Promise<any[]>{

    let _serviceIds = resources.map(s => s.id)

    //API functions with multiple parameters, return timeline object
    return TimelineAPI.getTimeline(planningType, planningType === "draft" ? draft.id : null, execId ?? null, solId ?? null, {
        serviceIds: _serviceIds.join(),
        start: horizon.from.format(DateISOFormat),
        end: horizon.to.format(DateISOFormat),
        "withDetail.shifts": true,
        "withResult.demandSatisfactionMeasuresByShift": true,
        "withResult.demandSatisfactionMeasuresGlobal": false,
    })
     //return a FullCalender events array
    .then(timeline => getSatisfactionDemandTimelineAsFCEventObject(timeline.result.demandSatisfactionMeasuresByShift, timeline.detail))

}
```

When I log the return of **satisfactionSourceEvents** function, I find my array of events, here's an example, as well as the resources sent to fullCalendar (`filteredResources state`).

**events** :

```
[
   {"start": "2023-11-01T00:00:00","end": "2023-11-01T23:59:59",  "resourceId": "1_2"}
   {"start": "2023-11-02T00:00:00","end": "2023-11-02T23:59:59",  "resourceId": "1_2"}
   {"start": "2023-11-03T00:00:00","end": "2023-11-03T23:59:59",  "resourceId": "1_2"}
   ...
]
```

**resources** :

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Service 2",
    "resourceType": "SERVICE",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "1_2",
        "title": "N7",
        "resourceType": "SHIFT",
      },
      {
        "id": "2_2",
        "title": "B12",
        "resourceType": "SHIFT",
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

The api return format is correct, since it hasn't changed and was working before the switch to eventSources.
Is it possible to use Promise in eventSources?

If need be, I can try to make a codepen, but it might take me a long time...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Fullcalendar doesn't directly accept a Promise as input, no. So what's happening is you're returning the Promise to fullCalendar, but not the events themselves - they don't arrive until the Promise is resolved, and fullCalendar isn't programmed to be able to access them.

As per the [events as a function documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) you can wrap your asynchronous request inside the function syntax provided by fullCalendar, and then use the callback passed into it to provide fullCalendar with the downloaded events, once your Promise has resolved.

Something like this:

```
events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) 
{
  var promise = satisfactionSourceEvents(planningType, filteredResources, horizon, draft, execId, parseInt(selectedSolution));

  //get a FullCalender events array
  promise.then(timeline => successCallback(getSatisfactionDemandTimelineAsFCEventObject(timeline.result.demandSatisfactionMeasuresByShift, timeline.detail)));
}
```

and

```
function satisfactionSourceEvents(planningType: PlanningType, resources: GroupResource[], horizon: any, draft?: PlanningDraft, execId?: number, solId?: number): Promise<any[]>{

    let _serviceIds = resources.map(s => s.id)

    //API functions with multiple parameters, return timeline object
    return TimelineAPI.getTimeline(planningType, planningType === "draft" ? draft.id : null, execId ?? null, solId ?? null, {
        serviceIds: _serviceIds.join(),
        start: horizon.from.format(DateISOFormat),
        end: horizon.to.format(DateISOFormat),
        "withDetail.shifts": true,
        "withResult.demandSatisfactionMeasuresByShift": true,
        "withResult.demandSatisfactionMeasuresGlobal": false,
    });
}
```

---

N.B. Bear in mind that the events function will run every time the calendar changes the visible date range, and will refresh with whatever is downloaded from the event source. So ideally, as per the documentation, your event source should make use of the start and end dates provided in the `fetchInfo` object, and use them to only return events which are within (or overlap with) that date range. That means you'll only transmit the events which are actually needed by the user, rather than a potentially much bigger set of events, many of which might never actually be viewed during that session.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I hadn't tried this before, but the result is the same. 
I tried to add `eventSourcesSuccess`  to force the return of events, I receive them in the function but they are not displayed. 

I notice that my api is called 2 times constantly, I think the calendar is rerendering because of a state somewhere, the problem is that there are a lot of elements around it that control some of its properties, I think it doesn't like... 
I'll keep looking

Comment: Ok. Maybe something else in React is affecting it, I'm not a React user so I can't really help with that aspect unfortunately. But in regards to the events not showing, can you debug a bit within what I've written? Can we decompose `promise.then(timeline => successCallback(getSatisfactionDemandTimelineAsFCEventObject(timeline.result.demandSatisfactionMeasuresByShift, timeline.detail)));` into...

Comment: `promise.then(function(timeline) {
  console.log(timeline);
  let events = getSatisfactionDemandTimelineAsFCEventObject(timeline.result.demandSatisfactionMeasuresByShift, timeline.detail);
  console.log(events);
  successCallback(events);
});` ...and see what, if anything, it logs?

Comment: Ok, by moving my fullcalendar component into a child component (as I had done at the very beginning), my events are displayed using your method), however it still calls the api 2 times, and more importantly, it calls the api back for every interaction, resource filters for example). 
I'm relying on a ref with its parent component to interact with it on dates, I think these refs should force the component to refresh constantly, so make 2 api calls all the time

Comment: `more importantly, it calls the api back for every interaction, resource filters for example`...yes that's what fullCalendar does, if you refresh the calendar or change the display it will refresh the events. Why are you using something outside of fullCalendar to control the dates, though?

Comment: Because the fullcalendar component isn't in the same component as the one that manages dates, filters, export function, views, etc... the structure is fragmented to have a completely customized UI. 
So I just update Fullcalendar according to the states I give it, and not the other way around, and I think that's the problem. I think my source problem is a little deeper than the use of my functions

Comment: https://ibb.co/NVpjf2b

Here's an idea of how my schedule looks when there are events on it

Comment: Ok. Well I can help you with how to get fullCalendar to read events. It's fine to have external UI where the user enters dates, if you then tell fullCalendar to change the date (e.g. via [goToDate](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-gotoDate)) to the selected value. Fullcalendar will then, if necessary, trigger the events function to fetch fresh events - your API should make use of the date range fullCalendar passes to it. I would just ensure your client-side code which calls the API isn't triggered by, or dependent on, the non-fullcalendar parts of the page.